# Proving the limit of the sequence of averages using the direct definition of a limit

Tags: real-analysis

Let $b_n$ and $a_n$ be two sequences where
$b_n = \frac{a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n }{n}$

Prove that if $\lim a_n = 0$ then $\lim b_n = 0$ only by using the direct definition of a limit (no limit theorems)

I started by noting that (by the definition of a limit) given any $\epsilon$

$|a_n| < \epsilon $

The hypothesis is
$|b_n| < \epsilon $

So then:

$\frac{a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n }{n} < \epsilon$

From this point on I'm kinda stuck. I guess I could use limit linearity since $\lim \frac{c}{n} = 0$ for any constant is equal to 0, but there should be a way to do this without.

Comment: What you are noting is very vague, you need to write it out more precisely. What does $|a_n| < \varepsilon$ even mean? What is $n$, what is $\varepsilon$? The essential idea of this exercise is that for large $n$, the first terms in the fraction barely make any difference.

Comment: Moreover, this is true not only for the limit $0$ but rather $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ whenever it exists.

Comment: I've made the edit, I'm aware of that but I wanted to see the proof for the case n=0 in order to then build upon that and find the proof for the stronger statement @QiZhu

Comment: What do you mean, "for the case $n=0$ ? That doesn't make sense with respect to the question. You need to be really precise when talking about limits, and for that, you should go back to the definition of what a (limit of a sequence) is, and try to understand exactly what the definition is saying.

Comment: What $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$ means is that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $N_a \in \Bbb N$ such that for all $n > N_a, |a_n| < \epsilon$. And you must prove the same for $(b_n)$. Given an $\epsilon$, you must show the existence of an $N_b$ such that for all $n > N_b, |b_n| < \epsilon$. Your abbreviated version is just leading you to doom.